# Why <Memory> could not be cloned?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker, worker, webassembly

I have written a code in javasctipt that use WebAssembly.Memory and I want to use this memory in web worker.
It is my code:

```
var memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial:10});
var counter = new Worker("counter.js");
counter.postMessage(memory);
var arr = new Uint32Array(memory.buffer);
//other statements of the code...
```

the error of chrome is:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': # could not be cloned.
 at http://127.0.0.1:8000/main.js:3:9

what is the reason of this error?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that a `memory` object cannot be transferred… Try passing only the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You just used `new` with `WebAssembly.Memory` in the very first line of code, right? This means that [`WebAssembly.Memory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory) is not just a buffer but a class instance with methods.

In general, you can't pass a function to a Web Worker directly and you can't just `postMessage()` an object with methods neither. You should pass it as an Arraybuffer or an Array instead.

```
var memory = new WebAssembly.Memory({initial:10});
var counter = new Worker("counter.js");

// Do not transfer wasm buffer by passing [memory.buffer]
// in the second argument.
// That will break the current WebAssembly program
// Since it will loose its ownership of the memory.
counter.postMessage(memory.buffer);

// A safer way is duplicating the buffer.
// By passing memory view instead of the buffer you will get a copy of the buffer.
var dupArr = new Uint32Array(memory);
counter.postMessage(dupArr, [dupArr]);

//other statements of the code...
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case memory.buffer is not shared array that i can use in the relation of 2 workers. Is there something like SharedArrayBuffer to share WebAssembly.memory between workers?